# sending get parameter from a input text in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I need to collect a get variable in Laravel 8 passed as follows:

```
127.0.0.1/search/keywordToSearch
```

I have this route created in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/search/{keyword}', [SearchController::class, "search"])->name('search');
```

My form is:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('search') }}" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="keyword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Keyword</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="pelicula" placeholder="keyword">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But when I push the send button the url obtained is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?keyword=safafs
```

How I must do about passing the input value to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this particular scenario you don't need to pass a parameter trough the route. Make it simple, like

```
Route::get('/search', [SearchController::class, "search"])->name('search');
```

In the controller declare the action like

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
  dd($request->pelicula);  // here you have your keyword data
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Yes, finally I did like this.